# Mule - Get SOAP operation with MEL

Tags: soap, header, mule, soapui, mule-el

This is my mule flow:

`HTTP Listener` -> `Logger` -> `WS:Consumer` -> `Logger`

```
<flow name="ClientFlow" >
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]"/>
    <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" doc:name="Web Service Consumer" operation="NewRequestTest"/>
    <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

</flow>
```

I send a SOAP message to my mule flow with `SOAPUI`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<NewRequestTest xmlns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Requests">
<xmlEntry>
<NewRequestTest>
<hiMessage>Hi</hiMessage>
<NewRequestTest>
</xmlEntry>
</NewRequestTest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to do the **operation** from the `ws:consumer` dynamically getting from the SOAP header with a `MEL expression`.

In what way it would be possible to obtain that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the [xpath3 function](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/xpath) if your operation is specified somewhere in the body of the request, in this way:

```
<set-variable variableName="operation" value="#[xpath('//theTagcontainingwhatyouwant')]" doc:name="Variable"/>
<ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" doc:name="Web Service Consumer" operation="#[flowVars['operation']]"/>
```

Please note that in theory you could take the operation also from the SOAP-Action header that normally comes along with a soap request, you can access it via inboundProperties

```
#[message.inboundProperties['SOAPAction']]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The problem is that when I deploy it, The return me an error and I cant continue: `Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Operation #[flowVars['operation']] not found in WSDL (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)`

Comment: Ok, now your problem looks clear. Well I think you can't. The only way is probally to have a consumer for each operation and if you don't want to do that you can always try to use CXF module or just create a soap request with a plain HTTP connector, at the end is just a matter of having the right headers. In this case you will need to split or extract data from the envelope yourself. Aniway In many cases where I did proxy from rest to soap for example I always used to have a flow for each call with a specific operation, It was explicit, easy to read and self documented.